# Method must declare a body?

Tags: c#, windows, project

This is my assignment:

> Design and implement a stringed musical instrument class using the
>   following guidelines:
>
> Data fields for your instrument should include number of strings, an
>   array of string names representing string names (e.g. E, A, D, G), and
>   boolean fields to determine if the instrument is tuned, and if the
>   instrument is currently playing. You are welcome to add additional
>   data fields if you like.
>
> A constructor method that set the tuned and currently playing fields
>   to false. Other methods
>
> 1. to tune the instrument,
> 2. to start the instrument playing, and
> 3. to stop the instrument from playing.
>
> Other methods as you see fit (add at least one unique method).
>
> Create a UML class diagram using a diagram tool (e.g. PPT, Visio) of
>   your choice. Prepare the diagrams and place them in a Word document
>   along with a brief description of your class.
>
> Create a C# class for your instrument. Be sure that your code matches
>   your design specifications and some minimal functionality is included.
>   For example, if you called the violin.play() method, you should at
>   least print that the violin is playing. Similar functionality should
>   be supplied when you stop playing, tune or call any of your methods.

My code so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;


   namespace StringedMusInsApp
   {

   public class Guitarra
   {
   public static void Main (string[] args);

       //variable that stores the guitarra's name
    private String nameValue;
    //variable to store strings
    private int numberOfStringsValue;
    private char[] stringsValue = { 'E', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'E' };
    //field for tune of the guitar,
    private bool tunedValue;
    //field for playing of guitar
    private bool playingValue;
    //method to set tune and playing false.
    public Guitarra()
    {
        this.tunedValue = false;
        this.playingValue = false;
    }
    // gets and sets
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return nameValue;
        }
        set
        {
            nameValue = value;
        }
    }
    public int NumberOfStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return numberOfStringsValue;
        }
        set
        {
            numberOfStringsValue = value;
        }
    }
    public void DisplayStringValues()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String Values: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < stringsValue.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(stringsValue[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public bool Tuned
    {
        get
        {
            return tunedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            tunedValue = value;
        }
    }
    public bool Playing
    {
        get
        {
            return playingValue;
        }
        set
        {
            playingValue = value;
        }
    }
    //Method to play the violin
    public void playGuitar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The guitar is now playing.");
        Playing = true;
    }
    //Method to sto playing the violin
    public void stopGuitar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The guitar has stopped playing.");
        Playing = false;
    }
    //Method to tune the Guitar
    public void tuneGuitar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The guitar is tuned.");
        Tuned = true;
    }
    //Method to stop tuning the Guitar
    public void stopTuneGuitar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The guitar has stopped tuning.");
        Tuned = false;
      }
     }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Error 1 'StringedMusInsApp.Guitarra.Main(string[])' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial.

Comment: And what would the error be?

Comment: Error 1 'StringedMusInsApp.Guitarra.Main(string[])' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial.

Comment: I've looked online for hours and cant figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This is *not* time sensitive. We don't need this done by tomorrow. You do. You're the one who are trying to do your homework the day before it has to be handed in.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did specify at the bottom that it was I in need of help, and that I needed it. I am only accessing the internet on weekends because internet is a slight commodity here in afghanistan, and this is the only time I get a week.

Comment: Guys stop bitching around and help the guy, I don't know how the question looks like before the edit, but this is his first program in C#. You should have body for the main method, remove the ";" and add brackets. Like David says this is entry point for your console application.

Comment: I get the removing the semi-colen, however I don't know what I'm supposed to place between the brackets

Comment: i read somewhere that I'm supposed to place a 

projectname object = new projectname

but no combination of everything I've tried makes a viable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you *exactly* what's wrong:

> 'StringedMusInsApp.Guitarra.Main(string[])' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial.

Look at your method declaration for `Main(string[])`:

```
public static void Main (string[] args);
```

There's no method body.  But since it's not an abstract, extern, or partial method, it *requires* a method body.  Define one:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Also note that if you *don't* do anything in the `Main(string[])` method then your application *won't do anything*.  It'll just open and close immediately without ever executing any code.  The `Main(string[])` method is the entry point for the application.

This would probably become easier for you to structure if you separate your application host code (the entry point, `Main(string[])`, basically the stuff that executes the program) from your logic code (the `Guitarra` class, any business logic related to what you're doing, and so on).  For something this small it's not necessary to break them apart into their own assemblies or use DI or anything like that, but they should at least be their own classes.

Comment: I had seen some of the C# microsoft developer pages describe this but I dont know what I should put there for this app. I am just beginning, this is my first class, and I am lost.

Comment: @AbelX.Cruz: Well, that method is the entry point for the application.  So whatever the application *does* when you run it would go there.  Defining a class like you are doing creates logic, but it doesn't *do anything* with that logic.  Think of the class logic you're defining as blueprints for a house.  It defines the house, but it *isn't* a house until someone actually *executes* on those blueprints.

Comment: I read somewhere on this website about separating classes, but for whatever reason I cant get examples or some coherent help i can understand in my ignorant perception. Thanks David, until now I've gotten nothing but negative banter or snide remarks. I came to this site for help, I dont understand what the point in belittling others gets for people.

Comment: @AbelX.Cruz: It's not a matter of belittling others, it's a matter of respecting others' time.  The point is that one should read an error message and perform at least *some* research and effort.  All you did was copy/paste your homework assignment and copy/paste your code and tell us you get an error.  You didn't even bother to read the error, or mention it in the question at all.  The way everybody else looks at it is... If this assignment isn't worth *your* effort, why is it worth any of *ours*?

Comment: I didnt know what kind of format to post in here. I've been working on this offline since last sunday, I only get net access twice a week here so all the research I've done has been over the last 18 hours, I haven't slept and I didn't think it would be a problem to answer questions about the error and the solution to it.

Comment: @AbelX.Cruz: The format can be discerned from the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/tour  Basically you present the information about the problem, specify the problem (like an error message, for example), and ask about the problem.  All you said was essentially "I'm in a hurry, here's my code, fix it."  How long you've been working is irrelevant.  How often you access the internet is irrelevant.  Just because you're under pressure doesn't absolve you from being polite and respectful to others.

Comment: I never meant to be disrespectful, and the impatient nature is is innate and instilled for years now from the army. I never know when I'm going to lose connection either, so being in a hurry is just a state of being here for me. I never meant to be rude to any one, nor had I in mind everything you just mention, I apologize.

Comment: @AbelX.Cruz don't worry everybody has rough start. Don't look the negative comments and down votes. Hope you continue with C#. Good luck :). David very good explanation !